# Ant design - How do i auto close select ("tags" or "multiple" mode) dropdown after each selection?

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, ant-design-pro

I'm using ant.design select component ("tags" or "multiple" mode) in a page, i want dropdown to be automatically closes after each selection. Now it remains open and i should click on other places in the page to close the dropdown list.

```js
import { Select } from 'antd';

const { Option } = Select;

function handleChange(value) {
  console.log(`selected ${value}`);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Select mode="multiple" placeholder="Select Countries" size="large" onChange={handleChange}>
    <Option value="country1">Country1</Option>
    <Option value="country2">Country2</Option>
    <Option value="country3">Country3</Option>
    <Option value="country4">Country4</Option>
    <Option value="country5">Country5</Option>
    <Option value="country6">Country6</Option>
</Select>,
  mountNode,
);
```

Comment: If you create a live example here: https://codesandbox.io I’ll try to help you further...

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Answer (score 7):

Simply change first "Select" component to this:

```js
<Select 
      mode="multiple" 
      placeholder="Select Countries"
      size="large" 
      ref={(select) => this.countrySelect = select}
      onChange={()=>{ 
          this.countrySelect.blur()
      }}>
    <Option value="country1">Country1</Option>
    <Option value="country2">Country2</Option>
    <Option value="country3">Country3</Option>
    <Option value="country4">Country4</Option>
    <Option value="country5">Country5</Option>
    <Option value="country6">Country6</Option>
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

```
import { Select } from 'antd';

const Option = Select.Option;

function handleChange( value ) {
  console.log( `selected ${value}` );
}

<Select defaultValue="lucy" style={ { width: 120 } } onChange={ handleChange }>
  <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
  <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
  <Option value="disabled" disabled>Disabled</Option>
  <Option value="Yiminghe">yiminghe</Option>
</Select>
<Select defaultValue="lucy" style={ { width: 120 } } disabled>
  <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
</Select>
<Select defaultValue="lucy" style={ { width: 120 } } loading>
    <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
</Select>
```

Use it's own `<Option>`

More info: https://ant.design/components/select/

Comment: i'm using it exactly, in "only select" component, it works fine, after each selection dropdown closes, but in (mode="tags") dropdown remains open.

Comment: @HosseinHajiMali  Notice Option Capitalized... Notice it’s being import on `const Option = Selected.Option ` It is a component that has built in functionality... Not the same as lowercase option...

Comment: Ok, you changed it and it still doesn’t work as expected? @HosseinHajiMali

Comment: Yes, i was trying to make it short, actually i did exactly same as the ant.design example in my project, but i still have the problem. if you check the ant.design example of multiple select dropdown you can see the problem also, dropdown remains open.

Comment: think of a modal and a multiple select drop down, it opens and where do you have to click to close it? its not user friendly to click on an empty place to close it, it should close automatically after each selection

Comment: @HosseinHajiMali Since it has built in functionality, you’d have to modify it a bit to fit your use case... See my comment above...

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Select } from 'antd'

const Option = Select.Option

const SelectComponent = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState('')

  const handleChange = value => {
    console.log(`selected ${value}`)
  }

  return (
    <Select
      showSearch
      mode={'multiple'}
      style={{ width: 200 }}
      placeholder="Select a person"
      optionFilterProp="children"
      open={open}
      onChange={value => {
        handleChange.bind(this, value)
        this.setState({ open: false })
      }}
      onFocus={() => setOpen(true)}
      onBlur={() => setOpen(false)}
      onSearch={() => setOpen(true)}
    >
      <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
      <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
      <Option value="tom">Tom</Option>
    </Select>
  )
}

export default SelectComponent
```

Comment: this changes the open argument in the state whenever you choose an option or leave the field. [@Hossein Haji Mali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4823855/hossein-haji-mali)

Answer (score 0):

### How I auto close my antd multiple select component after each selection.

- I created a state `openSelect` to control the open and close of the dropdown
- Added `onDropdownVisibleChange={() => setOpenSelect(true)}`
- Added  `onChange={() => setOpenSelect(false)}`

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Select } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  const [openSelect, setOpenSelect] = useState(false);

  const options = [
    { value: "country1", label: "Country1" },
    { value: "country2", label: "Country2" },
    { value: "country3", label: "Country3" },
    { value: "country4", label: "Country5" }
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <Select
        mode="multiple"
        allowClear
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        placeholder="Select countries"
        options={options}
        size="large"
        open={openSelect}
        onDropdownVisibleChange={() => setOpenSelect(true)}
        onChange={() => setOpenSelect(false)}
      />
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

I created the solution on CodeSandox. Preview [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-select-auto-close-n24fnt?file=/src/App.js:0-735)